# Create Symbolic link in Windows 2008 specifying port

Tags: windows-server-2008, symbolic-link

I have a Windows server 2008 where I have my website hosted. 
I'd like to do access the following URL:

```
http://example.com:8400/one/two/index.html
```

Using this URL:

```
http://example.com/site.html
```

I tried creating a symbolic link like this:

```
mklink /J 'C:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\site.html' 'C:\bla\bla\bla\one\two\index.html'
```

The link is created, and I can access to it going to:

```
http://www.example.com/site.html
```

But it doesn't load the content, I suspect, because the content needs to use the port 8400.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to use symbolic links to route different ports in IIS. You need to use URL Rewrite module and AAR (Application Request Routing).

Here is a link to get you started.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing